# Mvc View (The name *** does not exist in the current context)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-views

Just out of curiosity.
Even though my code is perfectly compiling yet I am getting a red line under sections that uses c# in the cshtml view. 
Once I hover over it I get (The name *** does not exist in the current context) 
Any Ideas?
Note: all references are added that's not the problem

Comment: Close VS, blow away all obj and bin folders in the solution, reload.

Comment: What happens if you load the View in question? Generally, errors in Razor Views won't prevent the project from compiling unless using precompiled Views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have that happen to me a few times already. Try to remove the reference in the project and add it again, that should fix it.